# Unable to load huge files using Load Data infile local into mysql

Tags: mysql, load

I tried to load huge data file eg 10 mb files into the db using Load Data Local Infile into mysql using a windows service. But it failed and the windows service stopped without any exception. I tried with files of small size such as 2 mb and it succeded.

Is there any way I can load huge files into the mysql db? And what may be the reason for the windows service to stop?

here is my code..

```
    public int UpdateDataBase(string query, string filename, Logger swLog)
    {
        int status = 0;

        using (MySqlConnection myconnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionCdrBank))
        {

            try
            {
                myconnection.ConnectionTimeout = 1000;
                myconnection.Open();
                myconnection.BeginTransaction();

                MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand("ClearTempTable", myconnection);
                mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                status = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlCommand mycommand1 = new MySqlCommand(query, myconnection);
                mycommand1.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                status = mycommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlCommand mycommand2 = new MySqlCommand("InsertToCdrDetailsTempTable", myconnection);
                mycommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mycommand2.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                status = Convert.ToInt32(mycommand2.ExecuteScalar());

                myconnection.Commit();
                myconnection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
                if (myconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    myconnection.Rollback();
                status = (ex.Message.IndexOf("Duplicate entry") != -1) ? -1000 : 0;
                swLog.WriteErrorToLog("");
                swLog.WriteErrorToLog("Error while saving: " + ex.Message);
                mail.SentMail("Error while saving:", ex.Message);
                swLog.CloseLogger();
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
```

where query is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'a.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_cdrload" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES     TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Are there any relevant entries in the error log? 10MB is not a huge file to load. I regularly load data from files that are many GBs.

Comment: nothing in log......actually it doesnt throw an exception when i tried to debug the service.It just stops the windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm loading up to 100 MB files into MySQL Blob fields. And this is just my artificial limit.

So, 10MB files should not be a problem.

Did you set max_allowed_packet correctly?

What do you use to load the files? Your own code or some tool? What MySQL Connector?

Comment: i'm executing it as a mysql text command from the c# code.I'm using devart for connecting to mysql.And where can we set this max_allowed_packet??

Comment: Google is your friend...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html
If you have MySQL Workbench, it's a server network setting.

Comment: tried setting the max_allowed_packet to a greater value.But still same issue...here is my code....  I have updated my code above

Comment: Does not look too bad :-(   What happens if you execute this in the CMD line?

Comment: executing this in a command line its just loads the data but when used in a windows service its stops the windows service and does'nt load the data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7546/discussion-between-jay-and-remy)

Comment: i found a solution.Well u actually stated that earlier,max_allowed_packet variable.I had set that but it wasnt updated.Now i just set it to a higher value value and the file was uploaded correctly.....thnks

Comment: Windows 7 Admin mode issue? :-)